# return the value of the object array after the cycle

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to sort the data from the object by the last two digits of the key, and output to an array of 4 elements.

I need to get data on dates 1 through 7, 1 through 14, 1 through 21 and 30. I cut the key into the last 2 characters, then decided to check its value through the cycle and return to one of four variables.

Unfortunately, I cannot get access to the data after I converted the object into a string, and I am also sure there are ways, much simpler than this, which I cannot guess because of my little experience.

I need an array like `[data1, data2, data3, data4]` where data1 is the summed up value of dates from `2018-10-01` to `2018-10-07`, `data2` summed up the value of dates from `2018-10-01` to `2018-10-14` etc

I would be grateful for any help or materials!

```js
var dates = {
    '2018-10-10': 14,
    '2018-10-11': 3,
    '2018-10-17': 5, 
    '2018-10-23': 3,
    '2018-10-18': 1
    }
    
let a = []
test = function() {
       for (var key in dates) {
            a.push(key.substr(-2))
            if (a.values >= 30){
            let b = a.values
            }
 }
return a
};

console.log(test());
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: i need an array like [data1, data2, data3, data4] where data1 is the summed up value of dates from 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-07, data2 summed up the value of dates from 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-14 and so on :) sorry for my language

Comment: Can you post the exact data structure expected in your question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an array for the wanted summed up days and iterate this array for adding the values.

```js
function test() {
    var result = Array.from({ length: 4 }).fill(0),
        days = [7, 14, 21, 31],
        key,
        day,
        i;

    for (key in dates) {
        day = +key.substr(-2);
        i = days.length;
        while (day <= days[--i]) {
            result[i] += dates[key];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var dates = { '2018-10-10': 14, '2018-10-11': 3, '2018-10-17': 5, '2018-10-23': 3, '2018-10-18': 1 }
    
console.log(test());
```

Comment: This is almost what I need :) Could you please tell me how to sum up the values, and not write the element from scratch? Not from 1 to 7 and from 7 to 14, but from 1 to 7 and from 1 to 14